# Number of events in any interval for a Poisson process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, poisson-process

Let $\{N(t),t\geq 0\}$ be a homogeneous Poisson process with rate $\lambda$. $N(t)$ is defined to be the number of events in $(0,t]$. Since $N(0)=0$ by definition, we can conclude that $P\{N(t)=i\}=P\{i \text{ events in }[0,t]\}$. Then, $N(t+s)-N(s)$ is the number of events in $(s,s+t]$, which is a Poisson random variable with parameter $\lambda t$. Since $P\{N(t+h)-N(t)=1\}=\lambda h+o(h)$ by definition, my intuition says that
$$P\{N(t+s)-N(s)=i\}=P\{ i \text{ events in } [s,s+t]\}=P\{ i \text{ events in } [s,s+t)\}=P\{ i \text{ events in } (s,s+t)\}. $$

Question 1: Is my above intuition correct?

Question 2: If it is correct, how can we prove this rigorously? Can you suggest a related reference?

Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This follows from the definition of a Poisson process. Any resource on the Internet can explain you that.

Comment: @KBS From the definition, only the case for the interval $(s,s+t]$ follows. But, the results for the other intervals should be derived from the definition. This is what I am asking for help.

Answer (score 2):

Your intuition is correct.

By construction, the process $(N_t)_{t \ge 0}$ is non-decreasing, right continuous. Moreover, for every $t>0$, the left limit $N_{t-}$ is the number of events in $(0,t)$.

The key point is that for each fixed time $t>0$, $N_t-N_{t-}$ is $0$ almost surely. Indeed, as $s \to t-$, $N_t-N_s \to N_t-N_{t-}$, and this almost sure convergence yields a convergence of distribution. Hence the law of $N_t-N_{t-}$ is the limit of Poisson($t-s$) as $s \to t-$, namely $\delta_0$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think we do not need convergence of distribution. Let me explain what I have understood. Since $N_t$ is a non-decreasing and right continuous, the set of points where it is discontinuous is at most countable, and hence its probability measure is zero. This is why $N_{t^-}=N_t$ a.s.. This directly implies that, $P\{N_{t^-}\leq n\}=P\{N_{t}\leq n\}$.

Comment: The key point is that the jump times are random variables with diffuse law. This does not follow only from the monotony and the right-continuity of $t \mapsto N_t$.